# I've upgraded to Windows 10 Home, how can I decrypt my drivers from BitLocker?

Tags: windows-10, encryption, bitlocker, disk-encryption, decryption

Since Windows 10 Home doesn't have BitLocker support (you can unlock drives though), I've decided to use different software. That said, I need to decrypt my BitLocker-encrypted drives. How can I do that if there is no BitLocker management? Do I really need to reinstall an older version of Windows just for that?

Comment: in the settings app under system you should be able to decrypt the drive.

Comment: There isn't, nor is it in storage section in there. Nothing with BitLocker in settings search either, nor decrypt or encrypt.

Comment: under Windows 8.1 it is under settings app->PC & devices->PC info. I have no intension to upgrade the Tablet to Win10 so I can't test it.

Comment: There is "Bitlocker settings" in about section, but nothing happens when I click it, so no idea what's up with that.